# Powershell to find registry key and delete it

Tags: powershell

I have created a small powershell script to find where registry exist or not. It it exist, then use command REG DELETE to delete it. But after run it successful in the first time, I check regedit and see it was delete yet. But if I try to run script again, it still return that it found a registry key was deleted before.

```
$a = Test-Path -Path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{23170F69-40C1-2702-1604-000001000000}'
if ($a = "True") 
{
    echo "Found!"
    REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{23170F69-40C1-2702-1604-000001000000}"
}
else
{
    echo "Not found!"
}
```

Comment: try it with 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{23170F69-40C1-2702-1604-000001000000}'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Problem is with your if-clause.

In the expression you assign the variable `$a` the value "True" instead of checking if `$a` equals "True". In that case the if-clause only checks if the assignment was successful which should always be the case.

Since Test-Path returns a boolean you could check like this:

```
if($a){
#$a = true
} else {
#a = false
}
```

If you want to make it more clearly readable you could also do

```
if($a -eq $true){
#$a = true
} else {
#a = false
}
```

Here is a link to the documentation regarding comparison operators in powershell: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)